# Which days of the week will Dev Days 2011 be held on?

Tags: discussion, devdays, devdays-2011

I'm wondering what days of the week the 2011 Dev Days will be held on.

Personally, the less time I have to take off work, the easier it would be for me to attend, so Saturday/Sunday would probably be best for me. The next best thing would be days adjacent to or overlapping a weekend like Friday/Saturday or Thursday/Friday. Tuesday/Wednesday-type conferences are difficult because I might have to take time off work around the actual event days for travel or preparation.

Have any decisions been made regarding the schedule?

Comment: I'm voting up your question, and the implicit answer :)

Comment: I'd suggest that those with tricky things like, you know, families and the like would consider a weekend schedule a major problem.

Maybe we could have some way to express preference? Like a set of voteable answers? I'll see what I can do...

Comment: @Mike Woodhouse - I see your point regarding families. Still, I think I'd rather give up 1 weekend with my family rather than 2 days of vacation with them. Also, some people have spouses who are also coders and can attend together! :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was hoping that Joel or Jeff or someone involved in planning the events would answer this, but in any case it appears the answer to my question is now known. According to [the event pages](http://devdays.stackoverflow.com/), DevDays 2011 will be held on the following days:

[San Francisco](http://devdayssanfrancisco-site.eventbrite.com/) - Wednesday/Thursday, October 12-13

[Sydney](http://devdayssydney-site.eventbrite.com/) - Tuesday/Wednesday, October 25-26

[London](http://devdayslondon-site.eventbrite.com/) - Monday/Tuesday, November 14-15

[Washington DC](http://devdayswashingtondc-site.eventbrite.com/) - Thursday/Friday, December 15-16